# How to get original path when alias fails to resolve

Tags: swift, macos

How can the original target path be programatically retrieved when the alias fails to resolve?

```swift
do {
    let resolutionOptions: URL.BookmarkResolutionOptions = [
        .withoutUI, .withoutMounting
    ]
    let _ = try URL(resolvingAliasFileAt: fileURL, options: resolutionOptions)
}
catch _ {
    // since non-resolvable, then retrieve & print original target string 
}
```

The existing StackOverflow question ["Getting alias path of file in swift"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348653/getting-alias-path-of-file-in-swift) does not cover original target path retrieval for the situation of a non-resolvable alias.

The information would seem to be available somehow because the Finder GUI `Get Info` will still show the `Original: /Some/Path` even if the original is not found or available.

Also, `mdls` metadata listing did not provide the original target path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can load the bookmark data using `URL.bookmarkData(withContentsOf:)`, then use `resourceValues(forKeys:fromBookmarkData:)` with `[.pathKey]` as the keys. Then, query the `path` of the returned `URLResourcesKey` object.